SQL syntax help for arbitrage calculator
So I am somewhat new to SQL, and i am trying to get data that i imported from a script to be manipulated in a way that's readable for a arbitrage bot.
here is what i have so far:
Image of database called "NBAgameoddsml" that i am inserting data into with python script
run_date/time is when i loaded the data in, gameid is the unique key that represents a NBA game, home/away_team are the teams playing, sportsbook and home/away_ml represents the odds from that book at that moment, and the pcts represent the implied probability that book thinks a team will win.
now i'm trying to use this data to create a new table that checks for arbitrages, and an arbitrage is when the two implied probabilities of home_pct and away_pct are < 1
here is the table:
    CREATE TABLE CombinedPercentages2 (
        run_date datetime,
        run_time time,
        gameid varchar(40),
        home_team varchar(30),
        away_team varchar(30),
        sportsbook_Home varchar(30),
        sportsbook_Away varchar(30),
        home_ml int,
        away_ml int,
        home_pct float,
        away_pct float,
        total_pct float,
        arbitrage_pct float
    );

so this data should look like this: and fyi run_date/run_time/gameid/home_team/away_team should be the same for every row so im not writing that.
row 1 should just come out the same as original row 1 but row 2 =
row 2: sportsbook_home = Fanduel sportsbook_away = Pointsbet US home_ml = -10000 away_ml = 4500 home_pct = 0.990 away_pct = 0.0217 total_pct =  (home_pct+away_pct) or .99 +.0217, arbitrage_pct = 1-total_pct
row 3:  sportsbook_home = Fanduel sportsbook_away = mybookie.ag home_ml = -10000    away_ml = 1025  home_pct = 0.990 away_pct = 0.088 total_pct = (home_pct+away_pct) or .99 +.088, arbitrage_pct = 1-total_pct
row 4: sportsbook_home = pointbet US sportsbook_away = Fanduel home_ml = -25000 away_ml = 1700  home_pct = 0.996 away_pct = 0.0555 total_pct = (home_pct+away_pct) or .996 +.0555, arbitrage_pct = 1-total_pct
and so on...

basically i am trying to iterate through each individual gameid, then get the combined probabilities of each sportsbook with the home sportsbnook odds away sportsbook odds and total/arbitrage pcts in a new row.
this should return 16 rows for gameid ab73fb40da041c5affd9c554bba24a45
and it should also return 81 rows for gameid 034de1c59f66e2b5c04929fe7816d90b
and so on..
can this be done in sql, if not python?
any help is appreciated!
i tried this, but it imported wayyy too many values and they werent accurate:
    INSERT INTO CombinedPercentages2 (run_date, run_time, gameid, home_team, away_team,                   sportsbook_Home, sportsbook_Away, home_ml, away_ml, home_pct, away_pct, total_pct,arbitrage_pct)
    SELECT
        ng.run_date,
        ng.run_time,
        ng.gameid,
        ng.home_team,
        ng.away_team,
        ng1.sportsbook AS sportsbook_Home,
        ng2.sportsbook AS sportsbook_Away,
        ng1.home_ml,
        ng2.away_ml,
        ng1.home_pct,
        ng2.away_pct,
        (ng1.home_pct + ng2.away_pct) AS total_pct,
        1 - (ng1.home_pct + ng2.away_pct) AS arbitrage_pct
    FROM
        NBAgameoddsML ng
    INNER JOIN
        NBAgameoddsML ng1 ON ng.gameid = ng1.gameid AND ng.sportsbook != ng1.sportsbook
    INNER JOIN
        NBAgameoddsML ng2 ON ng.gameid = ng2.gameid AND ng.sportsbook != ng2.sportsbook
    WHERE
        ng1.home_team = ng.home_team
        AND ng2.away_team = ng.away_team
        AND ng.run_time = '20:20:00.0000000'
    GROUP BY
        ng.run_date,
        ng.run_time,
        ng.gameid,
        ng.home_team,
        ng.away_team,
        ng1.sportsbook,
        ng2.sportsbook,
        ng1.home_ml,
        ng2.away_ml,
        ng1.home_pct,
        ng2.away_pct;





I think that a left outer join may be required as this acts as a cross join in the right circumstances.
1. Potential pandas solution
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create a dataframe that looks similar to the question
l1 = [["g1", "h1", "a1", "sb1", "hml11", "aml11", "hpct11", "apct11"]]
l1 += [["g1", "h1", "a1", "sb2", "hml12", "aml12", "hpct12", "apct12"]]
l1 += [["g1", "h1", "a1", "sb3", "hml13", "aml13", "hpct13", "apct13"]]
l1 += [["g1", "h1", "a1", "sb4", "hml14", "aml14", "hpct14", "apct14"]]
l1 += [["g2", "h2", "a2", "sb1", "hml21", "aml21", "hpct21", "apct21"]]
l1 += [["g2", "h2", "a2", "sb2", "hml22", "aml22", "hpct22", "apct22"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(l1, columns = ["gameid", "home_team", "away_team", "sportsbook", "home_ml", "away_ml", "home_pct", "away_pct"])

# create home and away dataframes then merge
df1 = df[["gameid", "home_team", "home_ml", "home_pct"]]
df2 = df[["gameid", "away_team", "away_ml", "away_pct"]]
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on = ["gameid"], right_on = ["gameid"], how = "left")
# add back in when numbers are available
# df3["total_pct"] = df3["home_pct"] + df3["away_pct"]
# df3["arbitrage_pct"] = 1 - df3["total_pct"]
df3

2. SQL solution

    select ng1.*, ng2.away_team, ng2.sportsbook_Away, ng2.away_ml, ng2.away_pct 
    (ng1.home_pct + ng2.away_pct) AS total_pct, 
    1 - (ng1.home_pct + ng2.away_pct) AS arbitrage_pct
    
    from
    (select 
        run_date,
        run_time,
        gameid,
        home_team,
        sportsbook AS sportsbook_Home,
        home_ml
        home_pct
    ) ng1
    left join 
    (select 
        run_date,
        run_time,
        gameid,
        away_team,
        sportsbook AS sportsbook_Away,
        away_ml
        away_pct
    ) ng2
    on ng1.gameid = ng2.gameid

